# How to set APP ID in phonepage facebook plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am integrated the Facebook login SDK in ionic APP. The Facebook login SDK is provided by Ionic. But I am stuck at step where I need to set the APP ID. [Facebook Login Guide IONIC](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework)

When I am running following command I am getting the error

```
cordova -d plugin add /path_to_cloned/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="23411414124141414"--variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

I dont know what should I put in place of "path_to_cloned". I am running the command from inside project directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read Step2 in the guide you linked. Simply, this tells you download the plugin locally and store it in a directory. The "path_cloned" is the local path where the plugin is in your PC.